# Memory Leak when Kafka Producer calling ProduceAsync

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have an application built in .Net that inserts messages in kafka but after a runtime **I get a memory leak**. When I detect the memory leak I review the objects that are created in the program and I find many objects of type `Confluent.Kafka.SerializingProducer+TypedTaskDeliveryHandlerShim<Confluent.Kafka.Null, String>`

The class where I create the kafka producer and send the message is the following:

```
public class KafkaRepositoryEvent
{
    Producer<Null, string> producer;
    string topic = "topicName";
    string broker = "brokerList";


    public KafkaRepositoryEvent()
    {
        var config = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "bootstrap.servers",broker }
        };
        this.producer = new Producer<Null, string>(config, null, new StringSerializer(Encoding.UTF8));
    }

    public void SendTopicKafka(Entities.Event objDataEvent)
    {
        try
        {      
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objDatoEvento);
  
            producer.ProduceAsync(topic, null, json);
        }
        catch (Exception exe)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(exe.Message.ToString());
        }

    }

}
```

I would greatly appreciate your support.

Comment: Everything depends on how your class is used - can you show how you create it, and how you pass events to it?

Comment: Also, how do you flush and close the producer?